# Get a list of changed files compare to upstream but ignore all merge commits

Tags: git

I am working on a linter, the auto lints changed files before commits are pushed to git.

Right now I can get a list files that changed locally by comparing local branch to the remote branch:

```
git diff --name-only origin/featureA -- .
```

But this sort of breaks when I merge master into the local branch. When pushing, the above command would give me all the files that changed in the merge commits thinking I made all those changes since the merge commit does not exist on the remote branch yet.

Is there a way to get changed files but ignore changes coming from merge commits?

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question: `upstream` (the target branch for your MR) is not the same as `master` (the branch you merge in regularly), is it ?

Comment: @LeGEC yah the `upstream` is the feature branch's upstream. so locally a branch `featureA` and upstream would typically be `origin/featureA`.

Comment: Thanks for asking that question @LeGEC, I edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: You might be able to do it over multiple diff commands. If there is one or more merge commits since last push diff down to the merge commit. Then diff the changes from before the merge commit to the upstream point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try a proxy using `git log` :

See if this gives you the list of commits you expect (try it out with different commit sha for `{branch}` and `{upstream}`):

```
git log --oneline --first-parent --no-merges {upstream}..{branch}
```

If the list of commits looks ok, you can turn that into:

```
git log --pretty="" --name-only --first-parent --no-merges {upstream}..{branch} |\
  sort -u
```

If you want a list of files (without the occasional `R89 {old} {new}` for rename detection): add `--no-renames`

---

Breaking down the options:

1. `--no-merges` will make git log skip the merge commits altogether
2. `--first-parent` will follow only the left-most part of `{branch}` history, which is the closest thing git offers in terms of "the history of the branch"
3. `--name-only` have git log list the modified files for each commit it lists
4. `--pretty=""` do not print any information (hash, message ...) when displaying a commit -- you are only interested in the list of files here
5. `--no-renames` turns off rename detection, so a rename will be displayed as two individual lines, one for the deletion of the "old" file and one for the addition of the "new" file -- each of the lines in the output will have only one file name, and nothing like `foo/{old -> new}/bar`, which is useful for human understanding but a pain for scripting

---

Caveat:

if you have a development workflow where you regularly merge other branches into your active branch (not `master`, other branches that bring in changes you deem meaningful), the `--first-parent`  above will discard these commits from your list.

an alternative could be to not put `--first-parent`, and instead say "do not include commits that are already part of `origin/master`" :

```
git log --pretty="" --name-only --no-merges --no-renames \
    ^origin/master {upstream}..{branch}
# "^origin/master" (the "^" is before the name) excludes commits
# that are already part of that branch
```